# Is there a way to add a Tour on all the pages/routes?

Tags: 8

I need to create a Tour guide for the generic elements in a page like Search bar, notification, sidebar. These elements appear on all the pages. I want to create a tour which is available on all the pages. The tour is being created using Tour UI module. Is there a way to create a Tour for all the routes available. Most of the pages are Landing page nodes and few view pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using the [Tour UI](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2018-10-28/steps.png) module, add the routes to [the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Futsl.png)

All node pages have the same route, `entity.node.canonical`

For view pages, they are unique. You can use [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel)'s Webprofiler module to see the route names, ex:

[image]

They are basically structured as `view.[view_name].[display_id]`

<sub>**Note:** display_id is also known as the [machine name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sy0cx.png) value.</sub>

---

> Is there a possibility to have wildcards in the routes? Chances are
> thin

There isn't. You would have to tinker with the Tour UI module's code.

> Also, is there a way to enable tour for a specific node?

There isn't. You'll prob have to use one of the hooks shown in tour_test.module to unset if the entity/node id is not the one you want.

---

Because of the routing limitation, seems to me like the core tour module was built towards showing how to edit or configure pages for administrators and not catered towards anonymous users. For your use case, you're better off using

**[D8: Bootstrap Tour module](https://www.drupal.org/project/bs_tour)** which is using the [bootstrap tour library](http://bootstraptour.com/)

> No need to be familiar with Drupal routing names to be able to assign
> a tip to a page, this modules works purely on jQuery selectors so you
> may add the page body class plus some jQuery selectors to target a
> specific page instead of routing name.

Comment: Thanks @No Sssweat for the reply. Is there a possibility to have wildcards in the routes? Chances are thin

Comment: Also, is there a way to enable tour for a specific node?

Comment: @MalabyaTewari see updated answer.